# Link to download safari 4.0.4 or mostly 5.0.2

Tags: macos, safari

I am in trouble that my safari browser version 4.0.4 running on mc os x 10.6.3 crashing each time during running sencha application by giving error -

Exception Type:  EXC_ARITHMETIC (SIGFPE)

Exception Codes: EXC_I386_DIV (divide by zero)

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread.

So I want to download safari compatible for mac version 10.6.3, tried very much but not got any link to download safary. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what your question is. How can you download "mostly 5.0.2"?

**You want a version of Safari that's compatible with OS X v10.6.3?** That's the latest version, Safari 5.0.3. Try [here](http://www.apple.com/safari/download/).

**You want to download Safari 5.0.2 for Snow Leopard?** You can grab that [here](http://mac.oldapps.com/safari.php?old_safari=15). Although that's listed as requiring OS X v10.6.4, which you apparently don't have.

**You want an older version of Safari?** Try [here](http://mac.brothersoft.com/apple-safari-4.0.4-download.html). They are still offering a mirror to download version 4.0.4, which is also compatible with Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used it in a while but it saved me a few times. Check [OldApps](http://mac.oldapps.com/safari.php).

Comment: Thaks, I checked that link but no safari version available for mac 10.6.3